# Smoothness of eigenvalues of Hermitian matrix function in multiple variables

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, perturbation-theory

Consider a Hermitian matrix $H$, with each element $H_{ij} (\epsilon_1, \epsilon _2)$ being a function of two real parameters, $\epsilon_1$ and $\epsilon_2$. I am aware of the result that even if all $H_{ij}$ are analytic functions of $\epsilon_1$ and $\epsilon_2$, this does not imply that the eigenvalues of $H$ will also be analytic functions of $\epsilon_1$ and $\epsilon_2$. However, if we dilute the conditions, will the properties of the entries carry over to the properties of the eigenvalues? Specifically:

1. If all matrix entries are smooth, but not necessarily analytic in the two parameters, will the eigenvalues of the matrix also be smooth?
2. Suppose we dilute the conditions even further. If the entries are $C^n$ in both the variables, then can we conclude that the eigenvalues will also be $C^n$ in the variables?
3. Can we make the same conclusions about eigenvectors?

Clearly, 2 would imply 1. However, I would like to know if any of these are true, or false. I would appreciate it if you could provide a proof, or refer me to resources that talk about such problems.

Thank you.